# Python Selenium select elements with similar class names

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors

I'm trying to scrape a site with Selenium in Python. I have found this question answered only in html: I need to select some elements with class name

```
<span ng-if="evento.quota>=100" class="ng-binding ng-scope">1,14</span>
```

But on the same page I also have elements with class name

```
<th ng-repeat="(key, eventoHeader) in manif.eventi" class="text-centerSport ng-binding ng-scope"     ng-class="{'different-color' : checkDifferentColor($index, manif.eventi)}">
                                    X2
                                </th>
```

And since I need to select all of those elements present on the page, I can't use XPATH. Is there a way to say to Selenium that I only want those element with that specific class name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you use XPATH?

```
find_elements_by_xpath
```

will return a list of elements.

Comment: but  they don't have the same xpath

Comment: //span[@class='ng-binding ng-scope'] for your example